# How do i find the shortest distance of specified points between multiple points?

Tags: java, shortest-path

I've input the points and found distances between them. Now I want to find which distance of `m` points is shortest.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;


public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();
        Point[] coordinates=new Point[10];
        double dist;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            coordinates[i]=new Point(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<m-1;i++)
        {       
            dist=Math.sqrt(((coordinates[i+1].getX()-coordinates[i].getX())*(coordinates[i+1].getX()-coordinates[i].getX()))+((coordinates[i+1].getY()-coordinates[i].getY())*(coordinates[1].getY()-coordinates[0].getY())));
            System.out.println("dist between "+coordinates[i+1].getX()+","+coordinates[i+1].getY()+"and "+coordinates[i].getX()+","+coordinates[i].getY() +" is "+dist);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: store them all in an arraylist then use collections.sort to get the smallest

Comment: So at this point, you basically have a bunch of numbers, and you need to find which of them is shortest? If that's the problem, then just start initially with the first of them, and then for the rest, keep calculating the minimum of (previous minimum) vs (current value).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: Consider learning something about Computer Science history.  This is a variation of the "Traveling Salesman problem".  You will not find a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way your for loop is designed, it is only checking one point with the point that was read just after it. You need 2 for loops to compare each of the points with all the others

```
for(int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
  {
     // compare point i with point j and store the smallest here
     // you probably want to discard points where i == j
  }
}
```

Comment: The comparison works the same way you did, but instead of comparing point i with point i+1 you use i and j.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a for-loop inside another one to go through all points per point. The first for-loop will go through every point. The second loop will also go through all points, so inside the second loop, you will have any possible combination of two loops. Then you need to calculate the distance and check if the distance calculated is smaller than the smallest distance calculated before.

In the end you'll have the smallest distance:

- 0.0f for points[] being size 0 or 1
- smallest distance for points[] being size 2 or greater

Here's some example code:

```
float smallesDistance = 0.0f;
Point[] points = ...;

for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        if(i != j) { //cant compare on point with itself
            Point a = points[i];
            Point b = points[j];
            float distance = ...; //calculate distance with pythagorean theorem
            if(distance < smallesDistance)
                smallesDistance = distance;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the greatest distance, just replace `if(distance < smallesDistance)` by `if(distance > smallesDistance)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the helper functions:

1. `distance`: calculate the distance between two points
2. `shortest_pair`: return the pair with the shortest distance

Codes are as follows:

```
import java.awt.Point;

double distance(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y));
}

int[] shortest_pair(Point[] coordinates)
{
    int m = coordinates.length;
    double shortest_distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int[] shortest_pair = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < m; j++)
        {
            double d = distance(coordinates[i], coordinates[j]);
            if (d < shortest_distance)
            {
                shortest_distance = d;
                shortest_pair[0] = i;
                shortest_pair[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return shortest_pair;
}
```

Example is as follows:

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.setSeed(0);

int m = coordinates.length;
assert m == 10;

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    coordinates[i] = new Point(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10));

assert Arrays.equals(shortest_pair(coordinates), new int[] { 2, 7 });
```